# How to type the configuration of the export module webpack?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to type this webpack config file here. I get an error. "any" refers only to the type, but is used here as a value. How can this be fixed?

```
   module.exports:any = {
      devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        historyApiFallback: true, 
      },
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right syntax is :

```
   module.exports = {
      devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        historyApiFallback: true, 
      },
    };
```